# How do I mock objects created in external method using Mockito?

Tags: java, testng, mockito

I am testing this code:

```
 /**
 * Construct confluence object
 */
public Confluence(XWikiXmlRpcClient rpcConfluence1, XWikiXmlRpcClient rpcConfluence2) {
    this.rpcConfluence1 = rpcConfluence1;
    this.rpcConfluence2 = rpcConfluence2;
}

/**
 * Method to publish new confluence page to Confluence
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */

public void publishNew() throws IOException {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 

    try {
        if (parentPageId == null) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to publish to confluence - required page id of parent confluence page is not set");
        }
        LOGGER.info("Logging in to Confluence");
        rpcConfluence1.login(userName, passWord);
        Page page = new Page();                    
        page.setSpace(owrConf.getString(ConfigKeys.CONFLUENCE_SPACE));
        page.setTitle(owrConf.getString(ConfigKeys.CONFLUENCE_NEW_PAGE_TITLE) + "_" + df.format(today));
        LOGGER.info("Adding new page: " + page.getTitle() + " to space " + page.getSpace());            
        page.setContent(reformatMarkup());
        page.setParentId(parentPageId);            
        Page newPage = rpcConfluence1.storePage(page);          
        LOGGER.info("New page: " + newPage.getUrl());
        savePageUrl(newPage);
        } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error publishing to confluence", e);
        }

}
```

using Mockito:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    confluence1 = Mockito.mock(XWikiXmlRpcClient.class);
    confluence2 = Mockito.mock(XWikiXmlRpcClient.class);
    publish = new Confluence(confluence1, confluence2);
```

}

```
@Test
public void testAddPage() {
try {
    publish.publishNew();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is this:

```
Page page = new Page();
```

When it tries to do:

```
newPage.getUrl();
```

I get a null pointer exception because this object is created outside the mocking framework, and I can't figure out a way to mock it up. Ideas appreciated :)

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.openet.report.publish.Confluence.publishNew(Confluence.java:79)
 at com.openet.report.publish.PublishTest.testAddPage(PublishTest.java:35)` Line 79 is where it does `newPage.getUrl()`

Comment: There is no `page.getUrl()` in your code. Did you post the right code?

Comment: Sorry, edited to use right method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a method on a mock object, you will get `null` result unless you specify otherwise. You must specify, what the method `rpcConfluence1.storePage(page);` should return instead of `null`. Learn about `Mockito.when` method.

For the beginning try to set it up in your @BeforeTest method like this

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    confluence1 = Mockito.mock(XWikiXmlRpcClient.class);
    Page testPage = new Page();
    when(confluence1.storePage(any(Page.class))).thenReturn(testPage);
    confluence2 = Mockito.mock(XWikiXmlRpcClient.class);
    publish = new Confluence(confluence1, confluence2);
}
```

Comment: For some reason I have to use static calls to mockito or I get a syntax error: `when(confluence1.storePage(any(Page.class))).thenReturn(testPage);` error is: `The method any(Class<Page>) is undefined for the type PublishTest` If I put in static calls: `Mockito.when(confluence1.storePage(Mockito.any(Page.class))).thenReturn(testPage);` , then I get the same null pointer exception on line 79.

Comment: It is a static method, sorry for unclear explanation. Are you sure it is still the same line 79? Because if you added some lines into the setup() method, then the NPE should appear on a different line

Comment: You are right the error has moved past that point - thank you!